# Retrieve id and handle it

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table, named "question".

[image]

I want a query that will retrieve the maximum QID from the table where I specify a Pid. Then I want to take the selected value and add 1 to it. I want this to work even if there is no value where Pid is for example 1 or 2.

For example if the max qid is 1 where pid is 1, I want a code to retrieve a 1 and add 1. If I in my query put "WHERE pid=2" and there is no pid=2 in my table, I want it to make qid=1.

I have this code to get the maximum qid-value but it doesn't work.

```
$qu = mysqli_query("SELECT max(qid) AS id FROM answer_det WHERE WHERE pid = '1' ");        
$result = $mysqli->query($qu);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
       echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: define "it does not work". What happens? What would you expect differently?

Comment: change `max(qid)` to `coalesce(max(qid),1)`  coalesce takes the first non-null value in a series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use ifnull

```
$qu = mysqli_query("SELECT ifnull(max(qid)+1, 1) AS id 
                      FROM answer_det WHERE WHERE pid = '1' ");
```

In this way if you try a query for a pid that not exist you get the value 1 otherwise you get the value +1